# Can I set the dynamic path in the query in SQL Server with json?

Tags: sql-server, json

I needed in dynamic json path in query, is it possible?

My attempt:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetValue]()
RETURNS @newTable TABLE (ColumnValue NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @jsonURL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @kek NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @kek2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @jsonURL =  N'$.glossary.title'

    SELECT @kek = JSONValue 
    FROM [dbo].[jsobj]

    SET @result = 'SELECT JSON_VALUE('+@kek+', '+@jsonURL+')'

    EXEC @kek2 = @result

    INSERT INTO @newTable 
        SELECT @kek2

    RETURN
END
```

When I call this function I get this error message:

> Msg 203, level 16, state 2, line 2
>   Name "SELECT JSON_VALUE ({" glossary ": {" title ":" example glossary ",
>   "GlossDiv": {"title": "S", "GlossList": {"GlossEntry": {"ID": "SGML", "SortAs": "SGML", "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language" "Acronym": "SGML", "Abbrev": "ISO 8879: 1986", "GlossDef": {"para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.", "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]}, "GlossSee": "markup"}}}}
>   }
>   , $ .glossary.title) "is not a valid identifier.

If I using next code, all okay, but it's don't that I need - no dynamic JSON url

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetValue]()
RETURNS @newTable TABLE
(ColumnValue NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @jsonURL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @kek NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @kek2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @jsonURL =  N'$.glossary.title'

    SELECT @kek = JSONValue FROM [dbo].[jsobj]

    SELECT @kek2 = JSON_VALUE(@kek, N'$.glossary.title')


    INSERT INTO @newTable 
        SELECT @kek2

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Are you sure that JSON is valid?

Comment: @JacobH Yeah, it's work if I use something like that:
SELECT JSON_VALUE('+@kek+',  N'$.glossary.title')'
But it's don't dynamic

Comment: I think I got it. You don't have single quotes around your path now. Include them in your SET and see if that fixes it. `...} , $ .glossary.title)` should be `...} , '$ .glossary.title')`

Comment: @JacobH No, it's don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to triple up all of your internal single quotes in your query, like this:

```
 SET @result = 'SELECT JSON_VALUE('''+@kek+''', '''+@jsonURL+''')'
```

Both the JSON string and the JSON url need to be treated as strings to be passed to the `JSON_VALUE` function.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it in the following way. Json using

```
SET @cTrama = '{"cPerJurCodigo":"1000000002","listaRemuneraciones":[{"nPerConRemElemento":1,"nPerConRemMonto":2600.0},{"nPerConRemElemento":2,"nPerConRemMonto":1300.0}],"cantRemuneraciones":2}'
```

The view of the SQL

```
DECLARE @cantRemuneraciones INT;
DECLARE @cant INT = 0;
DECLARE @ruta NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Parametros NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cantRemuneraciones = JSON_VALUE(@cTrama,'$.cantRemuneraciones');

WHILE @cant < @cantRemuneraciones
BEGIN

    SET @ruta = 'SELECT JSON_VALUE(@cTrama,REPLACE(''$.listaRemuneraciones[0].nPerConRemElemento'',''0'','+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@cant) +'));';

    SET @Parametros = N'@cTrama NVARCHAR(MAX)';
    EXEC sp_executesql @ruta, @Parametros, @cTrama

    SET @cant = @cant +1;

END;
```

with that I get a dynamic JSON_VALUE